# iOS taptic selectionChanged not firing for UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, uiswitch, selectionchanged, taptic-engine

I am unable to get the TapTic Engine to generate a `.selectionChanged()` when used with a `UISegmentedControl`, but it works perfectly on a `UISwitch`

Here's the code:

```
  @IBAction func languageSegmentedControlTouched(sender: UISegmentedControl)
  {
    self.tapticSelectionEngine?.prepare()
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.setLanguage(languageOption: sender.selectedSegmentIndex) ; self.tapticSelectionEngine?.selectionChanged() }
  }
```

That does nothing.

But this does work:

```
  @IBAction func movableToggleSwitchTouched(sender: UISwitch)
  {
    self.tapticSelectionEngine?.prepare()
    
    switch sender.isOn
    {
      case YES:
        
        self.tapticSelectionEngine?.selectionChanged()
        
        // Do stuff
                
      default:
        
        self.tapticSelectionEngine?.selectionChanged()
        
        // Do Stuff
    }
  }
```

If I replace the TapTic engine for the impact version then it works for the segmented controls, but I can't get the selection version working, despite the Apple docs saying this is the one I'm supposed to use.

I tried it without the async dispatch and no difference. I only tried that after reading [this tutorial:](https://www.biteinteractive.com/finishing-touches-haptics/)